# 504 on google Speech-To-Text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using google speech to text for synchronous request. My audio (flac file) is around 40 seconds. Lately I have been getting a lot of 504. This happens when I fire multiple request at a time (Around 30 request at a time). When I do them sequentially, the success rate is much more in comparison to when I fire them in parallel. Can someone please help if there's anything that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is there any accompanying text or further content in the 504 error response?

Comment: Yes. It says 504 Deadline Exceeded.